# Chainer - predict using GPU

Tags: python, deep-learning, gpu, chainer

I have a trained Chainer model that I want to use to perform predictions. I can predict images on CPU by default, but I want to use a GPU, and I'm not sure how I should do it.
Here is what my code looks like:

```
model = MyModel()
chainer.serializers.load_npz("snapshot", model)
image = load_image(path) # returns a numpy array

with chainer.no_brackprop_mode(), chainer.using_config("train", False):
    pred = model.__call__(image)
```

This works fine on CPU. What should I add to it to predict on GPU ?
I tried:

- `model.to_gpu(0)`
- `chainer.cuda.get_device_from_id(0).use()`
- convert image to a CuPy array with `image = cupy.array(image)`

With all of these options, I get an error:

```
ValueError: numpy and cupy must not be used together
type(W): <type 'cupy.core.core.ndarray'>, type(x): <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

What am I doing wrong here ? How do I perform predictions on GPU ?
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to have it to work:
Instead of using `cupy.array(image)`, I used `cuda.to_gpu(image)` and then `cuda.to_cpu(image)`. I'm not sure of the difference between these but still, it works.